# how to fix the 504 Gateway Timeout in Laravel/Lambda-Docker?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sqs

last time I have a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76640804/how-to-fix-the-504-gateway-timeout-in-aws-lambda-sqs), I have an app that was made using Laravel/PHP. It is running on a serverless architecture using AWS API Gateway,Lambda and SQS.

I have fixed the error by increasing the timeout in the saloon/guzzle connector

```
public function defaultConfig(): array
    {
        return [
            'timeout' => 300,
        ];
    }
```

Now I am getting the error again:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>504 Gateway Timeout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Gateway Timeout</h1>
    <p>The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;


use App\Http\Saloon\Requests\CreateModuleJob;
use App\Models\Integration;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class CreateModuleJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(         
        public array $information,
        public string $module_id,

    ) {
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {           

        $request = new CreateModuleRequest($this->information);

       ///here takes more than 30 seconds  
        $response = $request->sendAsync()->then(
            function ($response) {
                //emit webhook 
            },
            function ($response) {
                //emit webhook
            }
        );

        $response->wait();
    }    
   
}
```

the job is running on SQS, as I mentioned before, I solved that issue increasing the timeout, now I have increased again to 500ms, but the problem remains. I change was made in the lambda function 2 weeks ago, now it is using docker, I think the problem is docker, here is my vapor.yml file

```
id: xxxxx
name: xxxxx
environments:
    production:
        memory: 2048
        cli-memory: 1024
        capacity: 2
        storage: xxxxxx-bucket
        database: xxxxxxx
        domain: domain.com
        cache: xxxx-cache
        runtime: docker
        queues:
            - xxxxx
        queue-timeout: 500
        queue-database-session-persist: true
        queue-memory: 1024
        timeout: 30
        warm: 10
        build:            
           ....
        deploy:
            ....
```

What can I do?

Comment: 504 is a network issue, most likely happening when the application takes too long to answer a request. A loadbalancer will keep a connection only for a short amount of time, if the application doesn't send output within this time, the LB drops the connection, which results in a 504 on the browsers end.